# On unformatted hard drive after fseek, fread reads from start of 512 byte sector, not seek location

Tags: c, windows

I have a program that opens an unformatted hard drive (in the admin mode) and copy a large amount of data. Since the hard drive is extremely large I have to use fseek() to go through the hard drive fast.

First I iterate using the following function.

```
//pseudo code
int fd;
FILE* f;
HANDLE hDisk;
wchar_t dsk[512] = L"";

hDisk = CreateFile(dsk, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL,OPEN_EXISTING, NULL, NULL);

fd = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t)hDisk, _O_RDONLY);  //file descriptor

f= _fdopen(fd, "rb"); // converts file descriptor to a file pointer


//then I use,

FILE * pFile_A = f;
char test_seek_array[779];

fseek(pFile_A, 973, SEEK_CUR); 
fread(test_seek_array, 1, 779, pFile_A);

//end of pseudo code
```

The issue is that fseek() doesn't work properly (may be it's the fread()). when you do a fread() after fseek() it starts reading from the start of the 512 byte sector instead of the the current location of the file pointer (inside the 512 byte sector).

So instead of fread starting from the file pointer's current position, it seems it reads at the start of 512 byte sector.

why is this happening? the other interesting point is that fseek() with negative offsets seems to work fine.

Is my conversion correct? going from a HANDLE to a file pointer? It seems the OS wants to read in 512 byte chunks. could that be the issue? I did do the error checking after every fseek() and fread(). They all seem to be successful.

Any explanation is much appreciated.

Comment: Code is having I/O troubles yet the 5 I/O related functions do not have their return values checked.  Suggest re-write code to check the return values.

Comment: You do not test the return values of your `fread()` and especially your `fseek()`, so it is unsafe to assume that they were successful.

Comment: I did check fseek() return values and it's successful. Additionally, I looked at the file pointer location using ftell() and I know where it is. fread() also return successful. For some reason it keeps staring from the 512 byte sector.

Comment: you say the disk is not formatted.  the fread(), fseek(), etc only work with a formatted disk as they depend (inside the OS) on the formatting.  If you expect that there are actually files on the hard disk (I.E. the harddisk has corrupted the information that indicates the drive was previously formatted)  then look at the partition table and the boot sector of the main partition as one or both is corrupted.  You might want to read: <http://html5.litten.com/updated-how-to-fix-external-disk-drive-suddenly-became-raw/>

Comment: for viable options for accessing the data on a disk that was formatted but now reads as a raw disk, use google to find LOTS of articles on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED my answer:

you can simply open the block device.

The basic premise of open the whole block device will allow accessing the disk. with ability to fseek()

It is best to I/O a complete disk sector on each I/O operation at sector boundaries

Comment: I edited my answer to remove the 'linux' references.